# Systole of Riemann surfaces of genus $g$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, systolic-geometry

In Buser and Sarnak's "*On the period matrix of a Riemann surface
of large genus*", we get
$$\frac4{3}\le\limsup_{g\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\max\{\operatorname{sys}(S)|S\in\mathcal{M}_g\}}{\log g}\le 2$$
Here $\operatorname{sys}(S)$ is the shortest length of closed noncontractible geodesics in $S$, and $\mathcal{M}_g$ is the moduli space. However, I want to ask if there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
$$\liminf_{g\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\max\{\operatorname{sys}(S)|S\in\mathcal{M}_g\}}{\log g}\ge C\quad ?$$
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there is such $C$: It boils down to constructing for each $b$ a connected 3-valent graph of girth $\ge C \log(b)$ and with the 1st Betti number $b$ (the number $b$ is your genus $g$). The existence of such graphs is usually proven by a simple counting argument (a probabilistic argument). I will write a proof when I have more time.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks! I known the latter result, but why It boils down to constructing such trivalent graph? Does it related to gluing pair of pants along trivalent graph?

Comment: Not quite: Using pairs of pants would give a surface of small systole (cuffs of the pants are uniformly bounded). Instead, one glues together ribbon graphs which leads to a hyperbolic surface with boundary. Then one "doubles" such a surface "with a half-twist" along each boundary component.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry, I'm a little confused. Why It boils down to constructing such trivalent graph?

Comment: Sorry, currently I just do not have time. I will come back to this in about a week, unless somebody writes an answer which would be just fine as well.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks! BTW I think it's better if you give me a reference:)

Comment: @MoisheKohan , Note that strictly speaking, Buser-Sarnak are dealing with the homology systole rather than the homotopy systole. But a paper by Parlier saves the day.